# WP_MEMORY_LIMIT didn't work in wp-config, only within default-constants.php

Tags: wp-config, memory

i have already searched here and tried a lot of things, but my problem still is "alive"

It is possible to set `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` within the default-constants.php and this works fine, but every time I update wordpress I have to make this setting again. So my wp-config.php does not overwrite the setting in the default-config.php.

The wp-config-file was created directly from wordpress automatically.

I have checked [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/286072/wp-memory-limit-didnt-work-in-wp-config/286073#286073), my setting for `WP_MEMEORY_LIMIT` is directly below `WP_DEBUG` and before `ABSPATH` is defined.

```
$table_prefix  = 'hp365_01_';

define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define(‘WP_MEMORY_LIMIT’, ’128M’);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

Maybe somebody has the same problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code appears to be using he incorrect quote characters. You have `’` instead of `'`. This can happen if you copy it from a site where the quotes have been converted to ‘fancy quotes’ by the publishing platform but the author didn’t catch it.

So replace

```
define(‘WP_MEMORY_LIMIT’, ’128M’);
```

With

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');
```

Comment: just tested, it works now fine, thanks a lot !! ;)